# Tailwind CSS does not work with React App

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-modules, tailwind-css

I am trying to add tailwind css with react app. I followed the tailwind documentation,how to set up tailwind with react.

I tried with tailwind latest version.I checked Nodejs and npm are installed perfectly.

But when i run the `npm run start` it always get an error. I can't fix the problem.

[image]

package.json

```
{
  "name": "tailwind-css",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.1.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "engines": {
    "npm": "6.14.6",
    "node": "12.18.4"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "postcss": "^7.0.36",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.2"
  }
}
```

Please anyone help.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling ``node_modules`` yet?

Comment: this is not tailwind error

Comment: Sorry everyone, This error was in react scripts modules.Now working fine.Thanks all.

Comment: @MijanurRahman Can you pls clarify how exactly you fixed this?

Comment: @GeniusHawlah You need `react-scripts` v5.0.0 or greater for tailwind to work.

Comment: @MijanurRahman Next time, if you find a solution, you should add an answer to your question to help others who are facing the same issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you follow tailwind documents way, then try this, in the `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start && postcss src/css/app.css -o public/app.css", <--- need to inser postcss script as your css reference path.
    "build": "craco build",
```

and also check your `craco.config.js` like this.

```
module.exports = {
  style: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer")],
    },
  },
};
```

happy coding!

Answer (score 5):

Just update your react-script from v4 to lastest 5 version by: npm install react-scripts@latest.
If you will stay with version 4 you  have to use craco

That was helpful for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This fixed it for me. I updated my node and did a force update for npm vulnerabilities. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to
Write this in **tailwind.config.js :**

```
module.exports = 

    {
      content: [
        "./index.html",
        "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"
      ].
    ..///
    }
```